# SAS EG process flow not running the the right order

Tags: sas

I do not know why, but my SAS Enterprise Guide process flow is not running in the right order the i try to run the process flow.

It starts with some of the last queries (query builders). Is it possible to correct that mistake somehow?

Here is a example - where query builder 3 runs BEFORE query builder 14, when I run the process flow
[image]

Answer (score 1):

ooo has two very good suggestions. There is also one more way or creating order out of SAS EG chaos. 
If you right click on the process flow and create a new ordered list, you can actually add any SAS EG Project object from any process in an order. Later, you can right click the created ordered list and execute it. See the screenshots below.

Ordered lists live in special "Ordered lists" process flow.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

(I don't see precisely what you mean with so few information.)

But you can force execution orders by chaining steps with links

2 methods:

- right-click on the first step, "Link xxx to..." and the select the second step.
- click from the right side of the first step (when you mouse cursor becomes a cross) and drag and drop to the second step.

A dotted line will link the steps and the exectution order should be right.

If that does not solve your issue, please give more information, screenshots etc.

Comment: I have added a screenshot and some explanation to the problem. Hope you can help me now. Right now the only way I see, I can solve this is to manually make a ordered list?

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show much. What is running first when you run the process?